# How to use Crypto++ with Jni or NDK for a Android application

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, crypto++

I download from Crypto++ [Here](http://www.cryptopp.com/).
I find some way to build it with visual studio.
So I don't know how to use it for our Android application with jni or Ndk.

Comment: Do you know how to use it on a desktop application ? What do you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 1):

The Crypto++ wiki has a page with build instructions from the command line at [Android (Command Line)](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Android_(Command_Line)). The steps are:

- Modify the source files to accommodate Android
- Modify the `GNUmakefile` to accommodate Android
- Set a cross compile environment via `setenv-android.sh`
- Run make

The process will create the various libraries and show you how to build `cryptest.exe` and verify the library on a device. But you will still need to create you wrapper project using Android's build system.

Piotr Morgwai Kotarbiński has a page on building the Crypto++ library with Android's modified build system. See [Building Crypto++ with NDK toolchain](http://morgwai.pl/ndkTutorial/#heading_toc_j_2). I don't believe Piotr's article verifies the library on a device.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, and it generally goes without saying - read the manual of crypto++ on the desired subject (Android usage). Previous answers have kindly provided the links to the required documentation.

You should cross-compile the library for your desired linkage type (static/dynamic) - for that purpose you should create and Android.mk, which will describe the compilation process of the lib and then you should add that Android.mk to your main Android.mk as a module.

Alternatively you can search for a prebuilt binary and include this one in you Android.mk.

The process is not specific to crypto++, it's just the way to go with NDK.

Comment: This is closer to a comment than an answer. You should probably provide the `Android.mk` you talk about, and then explain how to use it.